# How to prevent site show cropped image on a phone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I have a perfect site look very good on desktop.

doc.awsri.com

[image]
But it looked crop on phone.

[image]
How do I adjust the css to prevent that from happening ?

```
<div class="col-md-3 margin30">
    <div class="default-wrap wow animated fadeInDown animated" style="visibility: visible; animation-name: fadeInDown;">
        <div class="img">
            <img src="http://doc.awsri.com/uploads/client/1545150130__FB_IMG_1545145675717 (2).jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
        </div><!--person image-->
        <div class="description">
            <h4>The man</h4>
            <span>ready to go</span>
        </div><!--desrciption-->
    </div><!--default-wrap-->
</div>
```

Is it because I set this fixed height of `200px` ?

```
.process-box a img, .default-wrap .img img {
    object-fit: cover;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Should I remove it ?

Comment: Most probably because of fixed height. It is trying to maintain the aspect ratio of images

Comment: What do you suggest I should do with the height of the image then ?

Comment: Why don't you use css media queries. Keep fix height on desktop and auto on mobile screen. Se how it goes.

Comment: remove object-fit:cover

Comment: @godfather, still crop after doing that, checkout the live site : doc.awsri.com

Comment: @PrakashSharma I tried : https://i.imgur.com/THJ9gAh.png , height auto, still see the crop.

Comment: not in media query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that the image problem begins at 991px width so. You will have to create a media query on your css file like below if you want to keep the height of your pictures 200px.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
  .process-box a img, .default-wrap .img img {
      object-fit: contain;
  }
}
```

In case you want to keep the width of the pictures 100% and lose the 200px height you will have to insert the code below.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
    .default-wrap .img {
          height: auto;
    }
    .process-box a img, .default-wrap .img img {
          height: auto;
    }
 }
```

Comment: With that suggestion, do I still leave my height or remove it ?

Comment: i didnt notice you had 200px height on the img parent also. If you want your picture to take 100% of the width on the mobile devices and not to be cropped you will have to take out the 200px fixed height on both img element and its parent div. if you want you img element to be fully visible with fixed height of 200px then you will have to change the object-fit:cover to object-fit :contain and then center the image element. Just make sure you make these changes on media query so that the desktop display does not get affected

Comment: Please kindly update your answer with the exact code you want me to try please.

Comment: Thanks I will try your suggestion, thanks for your help. I'm not so good at css.

Comment: Depends on what you want. If you want to maintain the height of your picture 200px use the first one, if you want the width 100% and the height greater than 200px use the second one

Comment: It was a caches on my end. so sorry.

Comment: It happens. If this actually solved your problem. mark the answer as the right one. Enjoy your site. :D

Answer (score 2):

i see you css on live site and think you should some changes with css like below

```
http://doc.awsri.com/client/css/style.css

.default-wrap .img {
    /* height: 200px; */
}

.process-box a img, .default-wrap .img img {
    /* object-fit: cover; */
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: have you seen this.

Comment: without breaking my existing functionality ? Do I need media query  ? U don't answer my question.

Comment: you have done on live site ? cause the site now show the proper image now

Comment: Yes, it is working now. I used *@Konstantinos Gounaris*'s code.

Comment: Thanks for you help